# Nested Single Query for concatenation of specific column in multiple row in single column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have currently working on sql server and writing a stored procedure to retrieve some data.
My requirement is as follows:

```
Table A:PersonId,FirstName,LastName,Address,CourseId
(Primary Key For Table B,Foreign Key Here)
Table B:CourseDescription,CourseId
```

Now for each course there might be multiple student enrolled to that course. My requirement is to concatenate each student ***LastName***,***FirstName***. If there are 3 or more student in a course we have to set another flag value as 'Y' in the result. I have done with Stored proc using temp table , and updating it step by step.
My stored proc is also like this:
temp table has column:

```
SeqId,CourseId,CourseDescription,StudentNameConcat,IsMoreThan3
```

First I update course id,description. Then from this table I looped based on sequence id(SeqId) and retrieve list of student name as column value and concat it in declared variable.

This approach is not good because it is not a set based approach and I believe there must be an alternative approach for it in a single query using inner query or loop join.I'm still reading and trying to implement it in a single query.But still not getting any clue.

Comment: If i find any good approach for this i'll add in comment.every one out there please help.Even good tutorial link on this also welcome.

Comment: Is your main question raising a flag when there are at least 3 people in the course?

Comment: yes sort of.because in UI i have to show a indicator that will be a link to display all associated student taking that course.And in UI all student name listing is quite cumbersome,if there are lots of student taking courses.

Comment: Then my answer should help you. If you want me to make some changes, just let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another table to keep track of students enrolled at every course:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.AsocCoursePerson(
    AsocCoursePerson INT PRIMARY KEY,
    CourseID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES dbo.Course(CourseID),
    PersonID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES dbo.Person(PersonID)
);
```

Solution ([SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/416da/2)):

```
SELECT  c.CourseID,
        c.[Description] AS CourseDescription,
        STUFF(oa.XmlCol.value('(/result/@PersonsFullName)[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') AS StudentNameConcat,
        ISNULL(oa.XmlCol.value('(/result/@PersonsCnt)[1]','INT'),0) AS StudentsCount,
        CASE WHEN ISNULL(oa.XmlCol.value('(/result/@PersonsCnt)[1]','INT'),0) >= 3 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS IsMoreThan3
FROM    dbo.Course c
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT 
    (
        SELECT  p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName AS PersonFullName
        FROM    dbo.AsocCoursePerson asoc
        JOIN    dbo.Person p ON asoc.PersonID = p.PersonID
        WHERE   asoc.CourseID = c.CourseID
        FOR XML RAW('row'), TYPE
    ).query('
        <result 
            PersonsFullName="{for $p in /row return concat(",",$p/@PersonFullName)}" 
            PersonsCnt="{count(/row)}"
        />
    ') XmlCol
) oa;
```

Comment: First character in concatenated name is truncated.for ex,AA ,B BB ,C CC which should be A AA ,B BB ,C CC.but i am stuck,where should i start,i am really novice to those terminology you have used in your code like XmlCol.value,OUTER APPLY,SELECT().query().so please help me to find a good reference.I am in chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11391/sql

Comment: @RawAliasCoder: Yep. `STUFF(...,1,2,'')`  should be replaced with `STUFF(...,1,1,'')`.

Comment: @RawAliasCoder: Using [CROSS/OUTER APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx). SQL Server [XQuery implementation reference (starting point)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189075.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Your data structure is not normalised. Unless a student can only be on one course ever. This is bad and should be corrected.

Apart from that, you are trying to emulate a `group concat` function. This is one approach.

```
SELECT courses.*, 
    LEFT(students , LEN(students)-1) AS students, 
    case when (select count(*) from @studentcourses where CourseId = courses.CourseId)>=3
      then 'y' else 'n' end
FROM courses
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT lastname + ' ' + firstname + ','
    FROM studentcourses
    WHERE courses.CourseId = studentcourses.CourseId
    FOR XML PATH('')
) t (students)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select
    c.CourseId,
    c.CourseDescription,
    stuff(
        (
            select ', ' + s.FirstName + ' ' + s.LastName
            from Students as s
            where s.CourseId = c.CourseId
            for xml path(''), type
        ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
    , 1, 2, '') as Students,
    case
        when (select count(*) from Students as s where s.CourseId = c.CourseId) >=3 then 'y'
        else 'n'
    end as flag
from Courses as c
```

A brief explanation. First, you concat you strings into xml, but name is empty and element data is `', ' + s.FirstName + ' ' + s.LastName`. After that, you taking this xml as nvarchar(max) with `value` method (this will keep all special characters in names, like `&` or `>`). After that, you'll have your name concatenated, but you'll have a comma before, so you need to cut it, using [stuff](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) function.

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/32f3c/5)

Comment: i have tried all these with small modification to my data model,but problem is how this stuff() function works with xml path.can you provide me a brief explanation or mention any good book on it?currently i follow http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/training/scripts/commadelimitedlist/,   still got no clues.:(

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to do is just flag each persons course if there are at least 3 people in the course, try something like this:

```
SELECT T1.COURSEID, 
       T2.COURSEDESCRIPTION, 
       FIRSTNAME + ' ' + LASTNAME StudentNameConcat, 
       CASE 
         WHEN COUNT(*) 
                OVER ( 
                  PARTITION BY t1.COURSEID) >= 3 THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 
       END                        IsMoreThan3 
FROM   TABLEA T1 
       INNER JOIN TABLEB T2 
               ON T1.COURSEID = T2.COURSEID
```

You can take a look at a working example on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/264e5/14).
If you want an explanation of how this works,just leave me a comment.

Comment: actually instead of 
2|  Course 2|  Sam Bawdekar | 0,
2|  Course 2|  James Cambria | 0
i want this
2 | Course 2|  Sam Bawdekar,James Cambria|  0